# different init methods being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm a little about this. I'm initializing a `UITableViewController` subclass `CTSettingsVC` via:

```
CTSettingsVC *settingsVC = [[CTSettingsVC alloc] init];
```

However, the `initWithStyle` initializer is being called. This is my m file:

```
@interface CTSettingsVC ()

@end

@implementation CTSettingsVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Why is this called?")
        self.title = @"Settings";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Why would you call `init` and implement `initWithStyle:` ?

Comment: @Wain it was a mistake and then I was curious why this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `initWithStyle:` is the designated initializer of `UITableViewController`. The `init` method of `UITableViewController` looks something like this:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    //NOTE: self is being used instead of super
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

Not all UIKit classes follow this convention of overriding `init` with default values for the designated initializer when one exists. I often do it myself if I plan on using `init` for a default initializer to ensure my subclasses are not broken in future versions of UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

`init` and `initWithStyle:` are convenience initializers for `UITableViewController`.  Internally they look something like this:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        _tableViewStyle = style; // Private, used in loadView.
    }
    return self;
}
```

The exception where you will not see `initWithNibName:bundle:` called is when your view controller is instantiated by a storyboard.  There, `initWithCoder:` is the initializer.